# Rails 6 - <%= link_to %> Is Not Opening Modal to Confirm Deletion and Just Deleting, How to Ensure Confirmation Before Deletion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome, ruby-on-rails-6, sweetalert

I'm currently facing a problem in my project. I'm on Rails 6.0.4.8 and Ruby 2.6.8.

The issue I'm running into is that I would like a user to be able to delete a notes record by clicking on an icon but when they click on this icon, I'd like this to open up a modal that asks them "Are you sure you want to delete this note?"

However the modal isn't popping up and it's going straight to deleting the record: NotesController's destroy method. This is the code in my views that I'm trying to fix:

```
# Where note is being passed in because I am iterating through @notes.each |note| to create <tr> elements with link_to's
# Using FontAwesome and SweetAlert
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-remove text-danger"></i>'.html_safe, note_path(note),
                                method: :delete,  data: {
                                    confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this note?',
                                    :'confirm-button-text' => 'Yes, delete this note',
                                    :'cancel-button-text' => 'No, keep this note',
                                    :'confirm-button-color' => '#BA3525',
                                    :'sweet-alert-type' => 'warning',
                            } %>
```

This is resulting in the confirmation modal never appearing.

I've tried:

- changing `link_to` to `button_to` but this just erases the icon from appearing and still results in the modal not popping up.
- wrapping `data` inside `form` like so: `form: { data: confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`
- changing `confirm` to `turbo_confirm` (obviously didn't work, but was a longshot because that works for me in Rails 7)

Nothing works so far and I'd like some help ensuring a confirmation before any deletion.

Comment: I see nothing technically wrong with your initial implementation. Are you using Turbolinks? How are adding sweetalert to the project? Have you required the necessary js and css? so

Comment: @engineersmnky Not using Turbolinks, I don't think. Using the 'sweet-alert', '0.0.4' and 'sweet-alert-confirm' gem in this project and importing `*= require sweet-alert` inside my application.css and importing `//=require sweet-alert` in my application.js

Comment: While these libraries have not been updated in years one notable item is that `sweet-alert-confirm` wants you to use `data: {:'sweet-alert-confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this note?'}` not just `data: {confirm: ...}`

Comment: Gotcha, I tried updating this to `:'sweet-alert-confirm' => 'Delete note?'` but it's still deleting the record without confirming. You bring up a good point however, these gems might just be deprecated.

Comment: I also added `//=require sweet-alert-confirm` to my `application.js` and now the `link_to` is going to the `show` route